# The network name cannot be found - Copy file with Python in Windows

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, copy, pywin32

I am trying to copy a file from a server remotely to where the script is being executed, however it is returning me an error in the connection, if I make the connection via RDP from winodws, I connect normally to the host

[Click to view the source code](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/442521-windows-network-file-transfers/)

**script.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#win32wnetfile.py

import os
import os.path
import shutil
import sys
import win32wnet

def netcopy(host, source, dest_dir, username=None, password=None, move=False):
    """ Copies files or directories to a remote computer. """

    wnet_connect(host, username, password)

    dest_dir = covert_unc(host, dest_dir)

    # Pad a backslash to the destination directory if not provided.
    if not dest_dir[len(dest_dir) - 1] == '\\':
        dest_dir = ''.join([dest_dir, '\\'])

    # Create the destination dir if its not there.
    if not os.path.exists(dest_dir):
        os.makedirs(dest_dir)
    else:
        # Create a directory anyway if file exists so as to raise an error.
         if not os.path.isdir(dest_dir):
             os.makedirs(dest_dir)

    if move:
        shutil.move(source, dest_dir)
    else:
        shutil.copy(source, dest_dir)

def covert_unc(host, path):
    """ Convert a file path on a host to a UNC path."""
    return ''.join(['\\\\', host, '\\', path.replace(':', '$')])

def wnet_connect(host, username, password):
    unc = ''.join(['\\\\', host])
    try:
        win32wnet.WNetAddConnection2(0, None, unc, None, username, password)
    except Exception, err:
        if isinstance(err, win32wnet.error):
            # Disconnect previous connections if detected, and reconnect.
            if err[0] == 1219:
                win32wnet.WNetCancelConnection2(unc, 0, 0)
                return wnet_connect(host, username, password)
        raise err

if __name__ == '__main__':

    netcopy('192.168.9.254', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Data\\connect.cfg', 'c:\\', 'localdomain\Administrator', 'pw1234')
```

**Output**

```
  File "script.py", line 13, in netcopy
    wnet_connect(host, username, password)
  File "script.py", line 67, in wnet_connect
    raise err
pywintypes.error: (67, 'WNetAddConnection2', 'The network name cannot be found.')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [[MS.Docs]: WNetAddConnection2W function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnetwk/nf-winnetwk-wnetaddconnection2w) (***emphasis*** is mine):

> - **lpRemoteName**
>
>   A pointer to a **null**-terminated string that specifies the network resource to connect to. The string can be up to MAX_PATH characters in length, and ***must follow the network provider's naming conventions***.

So it should be a share name. I modified the code to work in my environment (one change only - replace the *netcopy* call from `netcopy('192.168.9.254', 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Data\\connect.cfg', 'c:\\', 'localdomain\Administrator', 'pw1234')`, to **`netcopy("127.0.0.1", "C:\\c\\a.txt", "C$")`**, as I connect to *localhost* where I have some shares). 
**Notice *dest_dir* value: *C$***.

**Output**:

> ```bat
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q061107274]> sopr.bat
> *** Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ***
>
> [prompt]> net share
>
> Share name   Resource                        Remark
>
> -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> ADMIN$       C:\WINDOWS                      Remote Admin
> C$           C:\                             Default share
> E$           E:\                             Default share
> F$           F:\                             Default share
> G$           G:\                             Default share
> IPC$                                         Remote IPC
> L$           L:\                             Default share
> M$           M:\                             Default share
> N$           N:\                             Default share
> share-cfati  L:\Share\cfati
> share-public L:\Share\public
> The command completed successfully.
>
>
> [prompt]> dir /b c:\a*
> File Not Found
>
> [prompt]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_02.07.17_test0\Scripts\python.exe" code_orig.py
>
> [prompt]> dir /b c:\a*
> a.txt
> ```

As a side note, on the remote machine the user must have administrative privileges, otherwise writing the file might fail with *ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED* (*0x00000005*), especially since you're targeting ***C:***. It works for me, since my user has "*God* like" privileges on my computer.

Comment: It's exactly your code, except the last line, which I mentioned in the answer.